# Conscious sense

Tags: vocabulary

What is the meaning of "conscious sense" in the text below? I understand the meaning of "a conversation that doesn't make sense". But what about the word "conscious" in this context?

> He heard voices, echoes of conversations in the wind, like forgotten thoughts that made no conscious sense. The wind coalesced, and he did with it, his form returned to him at last.

The boy was flying with the wind and he could hear some voices and talking. I don't quite understand the last sentence.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case the phrase "conscious sense" means making sense to the conscious mind. The way it is used in this sentence makes it sound as though it might make sense to his subconscious mind, but it definitely does not make sense to his conscious mind.

Answer (score 0):

The *voices* like from thoughts are a mental quality without form in this example.

Then the voices and wind *[coalesced, sense 2](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/coalesce)* into his (I assume) physical form.